# modifying a frequency counter to make it a frequency meter

Tags: integrated-circuit, frequency, counter, circuit-design

[image]

Is it possible to modify this circuit and make it a frequency meter? This is an assignment and none of us know how to do that. We all have considered to make another circuit and not modify the one above, but it still seems impossible to do because the professor gave us a list of the things we can use. We can only use the components on the list below:

[image]

The two 7 segment displays must show the frequency we are giving to the circuit (we connect the fg for that). It must show frequency from 0 to 99 kHz.

Comment: I'd be tempted to say 'yes', as that's quite a large list of components you can use. Given that this is a homework question, what have you tried thus far?

Comment: we used the same circuit with the black background because we thought the objective was to make it count from 0-99 automatically. but the professor wants us to make a frequency meter. We've been adding condensers and resistance, but it gives us random numbers

Comment: Blindly adding parts won't get you very far.

Comment: Consider what each section does.  Specifically, what does the 555 do?  Also consider the definition of frequency.  It is (in this case) the number of pulses in a given length of time.  Typically, the number of pulses in 1 second.

Comment: The circuit is NOT a frequency counter.  It is simply a counter.

Comment: Your schematic is next to unreadable (technically, it's more of a wiring diagram). Do you expect people to google each component to know what each pin does?

Comment: With enough 74LS04 NAND gates and passives you can build essentially any sort of computer you want, to run any program imaginable... it just might end up very big and slow.

Comment: Thanks you, but the objective of this experiment is not to make a the 7 segments count from 0 to 99, but instead the 7 segments have to indicate the frequency that is given to the circuit. For example; if the frequency is 1kHz, the 7 segments should display 01, if the frequency is 34kHz then it should display 34.

Answer (score 3):

The circuit currently counts the number of pulses produced by the 555 timer since it was turned on.

What you want is the frequency. Put another way you want the number of pulses in a one second period.

The fact that you have to show the frequency in KHz gives us a clue. Using this factor of 1000 means that you only need to count the number of pulses in a millisecond period. Then update the display. You only need to do this once every update cycle.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks you, but the objective of this experiment is not to make a the 7 segments count from 0 to 99, but instead the 7 segments have to indicate the frequency that is given to the circuit. For example; if the frequency is 1kHz, the 7 segments should display 01, if the frequency is 34kHz then it should display 34.

Comment: @Eddie:  This is the correct answer.  If you have 1 pulse in 1 millisecond, then that is a frequency of 1kHz.  2 pulses in 1 millisecond is 2kHz.  I built a frequency counter using an old calculator and a timer back when I was a kid.  It was rigged to do a +1 on the calculator with each input pulse, and had a timer to reset every second.  It could only handle low frequencies (limited by the calculator) but the principle is the same.

Comment: @Eddie the definition of frequency is the number of cycles per second. If you count the number of cycles over 1 second, the number that you have counted is the frequency. If the frequency is 34KHz you would have counted 34,000 pulses. So, at the end of that second, update the display with that number and you have displayed the frequency.